# How to dynamically build a Javascript object based on a stream

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, stream

I am working with React and I want to render an object. The object must be built dynamically based on a stream of incoming JSON objects from a gRPC backend service. The stream comes in a specific form:

A main header object with a length property referring to the number of key/value pairs in the object. The object to be built can also contain nested objects. For a nested object the stream will contain another type of header object with a length property which refers to the number of key/values pairs in the nested object. I will call this a property header.

Let me illustrate with an example.
The following is the object to be built.

```
{
  name: 'John',
  address: {
    street: 'Kennedy avenue',
  },
  age: 25,
}
```

The incoming stream will be as follows:

```
{
  mainHeader: {
    length: 3,
  },
}
```

```
{
  key: 'name',
}
```

```
{
  str: 'John',
}
```

```
{
  key: 'address',
}
```

```
{
  propertyHeader: {
    length: 1,
  },
}
```

```
{
  key: 'street',
}
```

```
{
  str: 'Kennedy avenue',
}
```

```
{
  key: 'age',
}
```

```
{
  num: 25,
}
```

I push all of these objects to a state variable array in order (mainHeader at index 0). My question is, is there a nice efficient and clean solution to build the object? I would prefer if the solution did not depend on the `key` properties having that name. If possible the order of the objects and the length properties should be all that's needed to build the object.

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: "My question is, is there a nice efficient and clean solution to build the object?"
- sure there is, give it a try, and if you have difficulty, come back with more specific questions regarding what you've tried and what you're finding difficult.

Comment: Are you missing a `{key: 'address'}` somewhere?

Comment: Yes I was, I have added it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple implementation with no error handling.

```
function parseStream(stream) {
    var firstChunk = stream.shift();
    return nestedParse(firstChunk.mainHeader.length, stream);
}

function nestedParse(length, stream) {
    var answer = {};
    while (0 < length) {
        length--;
        var keyChunk = stream.shift();
        var nextChunk = stream.shift();
        if (nextChunk.propertyHeader) {
            answer[ keyChunk.key ] = nestedParse(nextChunk.propertyHeader.length, stream);
        }
        else if ('str' in nextChunk) {
            answer[ keyChunk.key ] = nextChunk.str;
        }
        else if ('num' in nextChunk) {
            answer[ keyChunk.key ] = nextChunk.num;
        }

    }
    return answer;
}

console.log(parseStream(stream))
```